# Error: Query input must contain at least one table or query

Tags: ms-access

I'm having a problem running my query in MS Access,
When I try to run this query,

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Login (workDayId, fName, lName, roleId, teamId, emailAdd)
VALUES ('100001', 'Richard', 'Baluyut', (SELECT ID FROM tbl_RoleDesc WHERE Role = 'EUC'), '(SELECT ID FROM tbl_TeamDesc WHERE TeamName ='Test')', 'test@sample.com')
```

I'm getting this error below.

[image: Error Message]

I've already tried to search on the internet but all the suggested solution is not working for me.

I think the issue in my query is the `SELECT STATEMENT` because I tried to remove that part and it worked.

Thanks!

Comment: `'(SELECT ID FROM tbl_TeamDesc WHERE TeamName ='Test')'` remove single quote from this then try again. So try `(SELECT ID FROM tbl_TeamDesc WHERE TeamName ='Test')`

Comment: @Harun24HR Thanks!, Still I'm getting an error.

Comment: Try my answer and let us know your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try on below query

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Login (workDayId, fName, lName, roleId, teamId,emailAdd)
SELECT '100001', 'Richard', 'Baluyut', tbl_RoleDesc.ID, tbl_TeamDesc.ID, 'test@sample.com'
FROM tbl_RoleDesc, tbl_TeamDesc
WHERE (((tbl_RoleDesc.Role)='EUC') AND ((tbl_TeamDesc.TeamName)='Test'));
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I've just edited some part of the query.